# Bluetooth custom plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a simple application with three functionalities, camera, google maps and bluetooth. I have used a custom plugin for bluetooth using **cordova 2.2.0.** When i debug my app on the device all works well but when i build the my html and js files using build.phonegap only camera and maps works, bluetooth functionality is not working. i can only click the buttons but nothing happens. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap Build service supports a limited set of plugins. You can see them here: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins.

Comment: but you can also make your own custom plugins and that is the one which is not working

Comment: if a plugin is not listed there it will not be build by the service, regardless if it is included correctly in the configuration file